# Swing: Instantiating a class with parameters for PaintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I have to draw lines and strings on a frame based on an array list and an integer coming from a different class. I have the following code to begin with:

```
public class test3 extends JPanel {

JFrame frame;
static ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
static int inputSize;

public test3 (ArrayList<String> headers, int inputSize)
{
    this.headers = headers;
    this.inputSize = inputSize;
}

public test3(){}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    test3 g = new test3();
    g.setUpScreen();
}

public void setUpScreen()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Graphics Test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(700,512);
    frame.add(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)(g);
    int headersX=40;
    for(int ctr=0; ctr<headers.size(); ctr++)
    {
        g2d.drawString(headers.get(ctr), headersX, 30);
        g2d.drawLine(headersX, 40, headersX, 400);
        headersX+=30;
    }
}
```

}

I can't seem to get the array list and the integer being passed from the other class. How do I fix this problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: 1- Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` before you perform your own painting; 2- Don't use `static` variables in this context, that's asking for trouble; 3- If you get rid of your empty constructor, you will be forced to provide the values you need...

Comment: if g is the class name then you should provide the implementation for setUpScreen